# Install windows 7 setup is starting stuck (Dell Laptop)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, formatting

This problem is taking too much of my time. I have dual boot (Windows 7 and ubuntu).Suddenly, I can't boot from both OSs. I have some important data in the hard drive. I couldn't fix it. Now I have decided to format the hard drive and install Windows 7 from DVD. I'm not able to install it. Every time I install it, Windows 7 installation gets stuck in setup is starting window. Some people suggest to reset the BIOS to default settings but it didn't solve the problem. Also, other people suggest to change the boot order, the problem is that there is no boot mode shows in my BIOS.

These are the pictures of the BOIS menu.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now my question is is there hope in this hard drive before I buy new one?

Comment: Do you have another HDD to test? Also, what happens when you try reinstalling Ubuntu (trying to determine if the issue is the installation media too)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshots helped, than you!
If you have not appreciated the very concept of data backup before - change your thinking.

Your basic problem comes down to this: fix or re-install.
Since you have made some efforts resulting in worsening the situation....

Your overall issue has nothing to do with the OS used (Linux and/or Windows).
Once loosing boot capacity it should have been a dead give-away to you:
You have storage device problems, the HDD or SSD inside your laptop just died.

Yup... Your hard-disk or solid-state is gone.